# How to tackle classification with string features?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means, random-forest

I am working on a ad-click recommendation system in which I have to predict whether a user will click on a Advertisement. I have 98 features in total having both USER features and ADVERTISEMENT features. Some of the features which are very important for the prediction are having string values like this.

```
**FEATURE**
Inakdtive Kunmden
Stammkfunden
Stammkdunden
Stammkfunden
guteg Quartialskunden
gutes Quartialskunden
guteg Quartialskunden
gutes Quartialskunden
```

There are 14 different string value like this in whole data column. My model cannot take string values as input so I have to convert them to categorical int values. I have no idea how to do this and make these features useful. I am using K-MEANS CLUSTERING & RANDOMFOREST ALGORITHM.

Comment: why don't you assign a unique value to each feature value?

Comment: @AshokaLella As explained in an answer below , my model may interpret those unique integers values as numerically significant values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful in turning a list of string values into categorical ints as the model will likely interpret the integers as being numerically significant, but they probably are not.

For instance, if:

```
'Dog'=1,'Cat'=2,'Horse'=3,'Mouse'=4,'Human'=5
```

Then the distance metric in your clustering algorithm would think that humans are more like mice than they are like dogs.  It is usually more useful to turn them into 14 binary values e.g.

Turn this:

```
'Dog'
'Cat'
'Human'
'Mouse'
'Dog'
```

Into this:

```
'Dog'  'Cat'  'Mouse'  'Human'
  1      0       0        0
  0      1       0        0
  0      0       0        1
  0      0       1        0
  1      0       0        0
```

Not this:

```
'Species'
    1
    2
    5
    4
    1
```

However, if the data are going to be the 'targets' that you are classifying and not the data 'features', you can leave them as ints in most multi-classification algorithms in SciKit-Learn.

Comment: This is really nice. Thanks. This will surely boost my accuracy results. But this will add up 14 more features to my dataset. M already struggling with overfitting. I hope this wont add to it.

Answer (score 1):

I like user1745038's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27192798/1760873) and it should give you reasonably good results. However, if you want to extract more meaningful features out of your strings (specially if the number of strings increases significantly), consider using some NLP techniques. For example, 'Dog' and 'Cat' are more similar than 'Dog' and 'Mouse'.

Good luck